# On Apple iMac Pro I have pressed Command-S but I have no idea what to do

Tags: mac, imac

I have an Apple iMac Pro that I was given by my neighbor. Her two daughters used it more but since have gotten tablets and time has passed as well as the master password from there thoughts and memory.

So I have no idea what the password is to even enter the CPU. I was looking to reset the user ID and password. I searched and have pressed <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>, and it got me to a screen that is in a language that is not what I thought it would be.

The screen has this `? /root#`

I can not tell what is before the /, but there is something.

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/HT201065 The previous owners should have done the first 6 steps, you need to do the last. You cannot give or sell a Mac to someone without wiping it, otherwise nothing on there belongs to you, not even the OS itself. Any time there's an update, you won't know their Apple ID, so you'll be stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Using 'Command + S' during startup will boot your Mac into 'Single-User Mode'. This is a tool that allows you to interact with your computer via command line input/typing only. This should only be used for troubleshooting startup problems, etc. and should only be used with guidance. To exit it:

- Type **exit**
- Hit **enter** on your keyboard

Your computer should now be back to normal.

---

Also, if you need to reset your iMac password, how about asking a separate question like:

"How do I reset my iMac password?"